# turn on fan using threads in python

Tags: python

I have this code where I use the method fan_on with thread

```
def fan_on():
    GPIO.setwarnings(False)
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    FAN_PIN = 23
    GPIO.setup(FAN_PIN,GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(FAN_PIN,True)
    t = Thread(target=sleep_fan)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
    return t

def sleep_fan():
    time.sleep(5)
```

when I tried to call the

```
fan_on()
```

the fan turns off before it reach the 5 seconds

When I tried to use the join() method

```
fan_thead = fan_on()
fan_thread.join()
```

the whole script sleeps and it is a problem

when the fan thread is on i also call this code

```
if args["alarm"] != "":
    t = Thread(target=sound_alarm,
        args=(args["alarm"],))
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
```

How can I fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to brief the problem. What should the program do while the fan_thread is sleeping ?

Comment: edited sir.....

Comment: If you really want it to be a never ending program, just wrap the main thread inside an infinite loop, keep child the threads as daemon and wait for user commands. To be honest I still don't understand the essence of your program. Without that, everyone will be just throwing some assumptions and probable solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make your thread non-daemon. This will make your script not until exit the `sleep_fan` thread terminates (i.e. for at least five seconds):

```
t.daemon = False
```

(Which is the default.)

For more info, see:

- https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#thread-objects
- https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.daemon

Comment: i tried to use it but the fan turns off before it reach 5 scs

Comment: Make sure that no other part of your script reconfigures or writes to `FAN_PIN`.

Comment: sir can you try to answer this question thank you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53579289/run-a-certain-code-while-it-detects-something-python

Answer (score 2):

Code  equivalent to your code will be

```
def fan_on():
    GPIO.setwarnings(False)
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    FAN_PIN = 23
    GPIO.setup(FAN_PIN,GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(FAN_PIN,True)
    //waiting code runs in other thread does not wait in this thread
```

**Writing a function for sleeping and calling it  as thread does not make sense to me.**
I think your desired output can be obtained with something like

```
def fan_on():
        GPIO.setwarnings(False)
        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
        FAN_PIN = 23
        GPIO.setup(FAN_PIN,GPIO.OUT)
        GPIO.output(FAN_PIN,True)
        time.sleep(5)
```